# Possible to prevent accidental bitwise operators on non-bitmask field?

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, bitmask

In C# you are [recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) to add the [Flags] attribute to bitmask enumerations, like so:

```
[Flags]
public enum Condiments
{
    None = 0,
    Ketchup = 1,
    Mustard = 2,
    Mayo = 4,
    Pickle = 8,
    AllTheWay = 15
}
```

I discovered I had code that erroneously performed bitwise operations on an enumeration without the `[Flags]` attribute that was not a bitmask at all (First=1, Second=2, Third=3, etc.). This was of course logically wrong, but perfectly acceptable to the compiler.

I'm wondering if there's any way to leverage the `[Flags]` attribute, or some other approach, to turn this into a compile-time error/warning. I don't know where to begin, but it seems like it should be doable, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest for this "custom" checks, where compiler is not able to figure out the problem use http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/. CodeContracts, if you can.

Comment: I've only read about Code Contracts but it did occur to me that might be the solution. Would this be a static check? I'd really like to catch stuff like this well before runtime.

Comment: Exactly. It something that you can run in order to validate your code against your specific logic and your specific rules. I think this link will clarify you all http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx

Comment: Late breaking addendum: I went to Code Camp NYC this weekend and it seems like AOP with PostSharp might also be a solution. It allows decoration of code with attributes to drive compile-time checks, as well as weave in runtime code.